# SilverStripe .htaccess redirecting to different page without changing the URL is not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe 4 project. I am trying to show a different page when the user visits the home page without changing the URL. I am configuring it in the .htaccess. But it is not working.

Following is my .htaccess file under the root folder of the project

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
RewriteRule ^/ /welcome [P]
```

When I visit the home page, it is still showing the home page. What is missing in my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change order of your rules to keep match-all rule at bottom
2. Fix your match pattern to make sure it matches home page only
3. Use `L` (last) flag instead of `P` (proxy) flag.
4. Also add a negative lookahead in `public` rule to avoid looping.

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ welcome [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.+)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: So when you visit `http://example.com/` do you get a page in `public/` directory?

Comment: Please provide details. What URL are you seeing in browser and what is exact behavior?

Comment: I am going to the home page '/'. The expected behaviour is that I should see '/welcome' page without changing the URL  which means that the URL is still going to be "/". Is it possible?

Comment: Definitely it is possible and that's what these rules do. What behavior are you seeing when you visit `http://example.com/` ?

Comment: Can you change first rule to `RewriteRule ^/?$ /welcome [L,R]` and see if that changes URL in browser. Make sure there is not other rule before this rule.

Comment: HI @anubhava, I tried this. But it still does not work.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.